# Xamarin Forms - HTML Entry

Tags: xamarin.forms, html-editor

I have tried to look around for an HTML entry/editor for Xamarin Forms but can't seem to find any. Has anybody got an idea how I can display HTML content and allow users to edit.
In my case I need to display notes that users would enter on the web application which has HTML formatting onto the mobile application. Users would need to see and also change the notes which syncs back to the office system.

Answer (score 0):

I think the library: [TEditor](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/TEditor) is what you need.  Works fine in iOS and Android.